# Mysql -> PHP: data type and number_format

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

I have two questions.

1) In MYSQL database, I have a column ("value") that stores baseball stats.  These stats can either be an integer, float with 2 decimal places, or float with 3 decimal places, or a ratio (4 / 10).  These stats are taken from an external data source and it is important that formatting does not change.  There are 90 unique stats and I do not want to a column for each...because of the different range of values that can be stored, I am using a "Type" of "VARCHAR(10)".

Is that the correct approach for "Type" given my requirements?

2) Using the same field from 1), when I query MYSQL with PHP, it returns my stat ("AVG") with string value of ".270".  If I don't format the value, PHP returns it as --> ".27"

I tried using "number_format".  The following code partially works for my case:

```
if($stat === 'AVG'){
$temp[] = array('v' =>  number_format($val, 3, ',', ','));
}
```

returns --> "0,270".  However, when I replace the dec_point with "." or do not include as it is an optional field with number_format, I still get ".27" instead of "0.270"

This is not working (returns --> ".27"):

```
if($stat === 'AVG'){
$temp[] = array('v' =>  number_format($val, 3, '.', '.'));
}
```

Also not working (returns --> ".27"):

```
if($stat === 'AVG'){
        $temp[] = array('v' =>  number_format($val, 3));
        }
```

I guess regardless, it still won't get me to ".270" since it will return "0.270".  How can I keep my numeric formatting and return ".270"?

I have tried settype($val, 'float') as well as intval after reading some helpful posts on Stackoverflow, but neither worked.

Comment: The last two number_format() give me always 0.270, it's correct.

Comment: For the second question, you are correct.  I found that during the subsequent json_encode I was performing, I used "JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK" which I believe altered the format.